# What's IOS Safari maximum webpage width limitation (showing error --> a problem repeatedly occurred)

Tags: html, css, ios

IOS Safari is crashing on my website's home page in 2022 on latest ios. I can't figure out the exact problem. My home page is currently a desktop only site which loads quick and nicely on android and windows but shows an error (a problem repeatedly occurred) in ios 14-15. Previous ios versions wasn't showing the error. Fun fact I have the same code plus additional media query code for small devices with little bit reduction in main div's width. The pages with working media queries are not crashing on safari. I don't believe that just reduction of total page width from 3554px to 2358px can fix the error. Safari should be more than capable for this much width. There should be some other problems causing this error. I tried removing CSS animations and transform scale but didn't help. Anyone knows about this problem and how to fix this please I need help ... thanks in advance ...

CSS

```
#Web_1920__1 {
position: absolute;
width: 3554px;
height: 2346px;
border: 0px grey solid;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
overflow: visible;
--web-view-name: Web 1920 – 1;
--web-view-id: Web_1920__1;
--web-scale-to-fit: true;
--web-scale-to-fit-type: width;
--web-scale-on-resize: true;
--web-center-horizontally: true;
--web-enable-deep-linking: true;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 615px)
{   
#Web_1920__1 
{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    width: 2358px;
    height: 5216px;
    overflow: visible;
}}
```

Those variables are for javascript and I think they're not causing the mentioned problem in the title ...

[image: IOS Safari error message on my website]

Comment: Check out the home page if you're on ios https://elomymelo.com/index.html this page shows error but the article page loads okay https://elomymelo.com/jbl%20flip%206%20meaningful%20upgrade.html

Comment: Could you give the specific error message?

Comment: The exact error message is - A problem repeatedly occurred on (the site address)

Comment: Are you sure it's the width issue? When you change those CSS values does it load correctly?

Comment: Not exactly sure that it's the width issue because I had the initial version of my site which was 100kb lighter than now with same big width and height structure but that initial version loaded just fine on IOS Safari. Now the article page that has mobile responsive code with width 2358px loads also fine. So reducing the width little bit more than 1000px seems to solve it (like width should be within 2500px). I think default IOS safari viewport width is 980px still I don't believe that 3554px is too much. There should be other reasons that I don't know yet ...

Answer (score 0):

the problem is because the **width** and **height** are too large.

try using 375px width and 600px height

Comment: This is too low to work with. Safari should have limitations of height and width a lot more than that. Someone said safari can handle 20000px in height. Don't know about the width. Something else going on with new IOS safari and my website